# How do I know when the queue ends that my thread consumes MQ messages

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, ibm-mq

My need is to consume the messages from an MQ queue and then close my console application when finalizing queue consumption. I do not know when messages are in the queue. The reading I'm able to do successfully, however I do not know when I finish consuming the queue leaving my thread open. I need to know how I can identify this moment.

```
    this.connection = cf.CreateConnection();

        this.connection.ExceptionListener = new ExceptionListener(this.OnException);

        this.session = this.connection.CreateSession(true, AcknowledgeMode.AutoAcknowledge); // sessão com controle de transação

        IDestination destQueue = this.session.CreateQueue(filaMensagem);

        this.consumer = this.session.CreateConsumer(destQueue);

        // Create an AutoResetEvent for signalling between threads
        using (this.receiveCompleteEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false))
        {
            // Create and register the listener
            this.consumer.MessageListener = new MessageListener(this.OnNewMessageCallback); // Callback for message handling

            // Start the connection
            this.connection.Start();

            // Block and wait for the receiveCompleteEvent event to be signalled.
            this.receiveCompleteEvent.WaitOne();
        }

        // dispose receiveCompleteEvent
        this.consumer.Close();

        this.session.Close();

        this.connection.Close();
```

Comment: "Consuming the queue" is not exactly the correct usage scenario for a message queue.  Messages can arrive at any time, quite unpredictably, you'd normally favor quickly responding to them.  So for one you'd consider leaving the program forever.  Note that the AutoResetEvent seems designed to quit when only a single message is received, you certainly wouldn't want that.  The easiest way is to use Console.ReadLine() instead, the proverbial "press Enter to continue".

Comment: In my context this will happen in the background. We will not have any user interaction. I will have a routine that will run the application a few times a day and consume the queue at that moment, so we will use MQ to manage the message queue.

Comment: Sure, nobody is very likely to enjoy waiting for it.  Doing this in a service is often the right approach, running forever until the machine admin thinks it is a good idea to stop it because of some kind of maintenance operation.

Comment: Don't use a async message listener, just use a synch consumer directly.

Comment: The queue manager will return you a 2033 reason code when the queue is empty. Best practice is usually to wait a little time after that happens in case more messages turn up before ending. Additional best practice is to have your application trigger started to begin reading messages again when they show up on the queue.